# How to get input values from print preview using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this sample html content with fields
I need to print all content including input values and display it on sample preview.
I tried this script to trigger the print:

The sample printing is working fine however, the input values is not displaying. How can I achieve that? Should I use alternative other than html() function?

```js
function PrintPreview() {
  printWindow = window.open("", "", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=650,height=600");
  printWindow.document.write($('#mainbody').html());
  printWindow.document.close();
  printWindow.focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="mainbody">
  Last Name
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">First Name
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">Middle Name
  <input type="text" id="mname" name="mname">
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="PrintPreview();" value="Print Preview" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me - copy the value to the value attribute and clone the div

```
function PrintPreview() {
  $("#mainbody > input").each(function() { 
    $(this).attr("value",$(this).val()); 
  });

  var printWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "location,status,scrollbars,width=650,height=600");
  if (printWindow) {
    printWindow.document.write($('#mainbody').clone(true)[0].innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();
  }
  else alert("Please allow popups");
}
```

Alternatively

[How to print only one div content from html page using print button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667390/how-to-print-only-one-div-content-from-html-page-using-print-button)

Comment: Alternatively give the div a class and hide everything except it using print css - then you do not need to open a popup

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code below before PrintPreview function:

```
$('input').each(function(){
    $(this).keyup(function(){
        $(this).attr('value',$(this).val());
    });
});
```

That way the value attribute is changed on keyup and the preview will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

This one try .

```
<div id="mainbody">
  Last Name <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
  First Name<input type="text" id="fname"  name="fname">
  Middle Name<input type="text"  id="mname" name="mname">
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="PrintPreview();" value="Print Preview" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
      function PrintPreview() {
     window.print();
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: That is not what is asked - that will print everything, including the print button unless you hide it